# After re-rendering an element view in cakephp, how do i rebind javascript events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cakephp

Overview of my situation -

I have a database with 2 tables in it. The first table is called 'primary_content_areas', the second table is called 'secondary_content_areas'. The only important thing to note is that each one contains an ID and the 'secondary_content_areas' table has a field called primary_content_area_id. The primary_content_areas Model has a hasMany relationship with secondary_content_areas.

Using the Cakephp framework, i have an element view, called Primary, which contains a div. Inside the div there's a foreach loop that loops through the data passed in from the controller and creates divs according to how many secondary_content_areas have a primary_content_area_id that is equal to the current primary_content_area id. The database basically creates a tree structure that is then recursively looped through and draws divs inside divs. Currently it is only 2 layered. An 'add' button is also inside the 'Primary' element view. When this add button is clicked, using jquery it creates a new object in the secondary_content_areas table and assigns the field 'primary_content_areas_id' to the ID of the div that the add button belongs too. Then in the same jquery process, if it succeeds, it loads a function in the controller that re-renders the 'Primary' element view. Because of how it is set up, this actually re-renders every div from the from the 'Primary' divs too all secondary divs  connected.

My Problem -

I have this working. My problem is that after i click the button once, it adds a 'secondary' object to the database, and renders a new div, but after that the button doesn't work. After some research, i believe it's to do with the fact that re-rendering a view and more specifically the 'add' button using jquery basically unbinds all events from the DOM.

So my question is how do i re-bind my jquery events using cakephp.

Here is the code.

Controller ----

```
...

public function add_secondary () {


    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    // check user is logged in
    if($this->Session->read('Auth.User'))
    {
        $this->Secondary->create();
        $content_area_id = $this->request->data['primary_content_area_id'];
        $this->Secondary->set('primary_content_area_id', $content_area_id);
        $this->Secondary->set('position', '1');


        if ($this->Column->save($this->request->data))
            {

                $result = array('result' => 'success', 'text' => 'Column Added');

            }
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
    die();

}

public function ajax_render () {
        $this->Primary->recursive = 5;
        $page_data = $this->Primary->find('first',array('conditions' => array('Primary.name' => 'index' ))); //temporary
        $this->set('page_data', $page_data);
        $this->render('/elements/primary');
    }
...
```

My best guess was i felt like i needed a line after  ' $this->render('/elements/primary'); ' That calls my ' bindEvents(); ' function in my Js. I haven't been able to find a way to call a js function from my controller though using cakephp.

Primary element view ---

```
<?php foreach($page_data['ContentArea'] as $contentArea){  ?>
<div class="content_area <?php echo $contentArea['tags'] ?>" >
    <?php echo $this->element('secondary', array( "contentArea" => $contentArea));?>
    <div class="button_container">
        <div class="add_button content_area_add_button">
            <input class="add_content_area" id="add_content_area" type="submit" value="add" data-content-area-id="<?php echo $contentArea['id']?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS ----

```
function bindEvents() {
$("#add_content_area").click(function() {
    //alert($(this).data("content-area-id"));
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/pages/add_secondary/",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { content_area_id: $(this).data("content-area-id") }
    });

    request.done(function(result) {
        if(result.result == "success")
        {
            alert( "success" );
            $('#content').load('/pages/ajax_render/', function() {
                alert( "Load was performed." );
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Comment " + result.result + ": " + result.text);
        }
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });

});

}


$(document).ready(function() {
    bindEvents();
});
```

PS. The 'alert( "Load was performed." )' doesn't happen. I believe i have the syntax is right where it is meant to alert that message when it has completed the load. It does not.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rebinding your events, consider using event delegation from a parent element (that doesn't change), then you won't need to rebind anything:

```
$("body").on('click', '#add_content_area', function(){
  .. do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put the JS code in a file, and call it in afterRender() function

```
function afterRender() 
{
  echo $this->Html->script('UR JS', array('inline'=>false));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'm not sure how relevant this will be to others but thought I'd post how i fixed this. Turns out i just forgot the line `$this->layout = 'ajax';` in `public function ajax_render();` . Once i added that in, the `alert( "Load was performed." );` happened. instead i replaced that alert with `bindEvents();` so after the load was completed for my ajax_render function it called bindEvents() again.

Comment: This worked for me, although Rob M's answer seems a lot more simplistic and is probably the better way to go about it.